# Derived Custom Control to Inherit Base Control Skin

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible for a derived controls to inherit his base control skin.

Say I am deriving a control from TextBox, is it possible for the derived control to inherit the skin settings for Textbox or do they need to be defined again?

I am applying the default skins to all controls through the styleSheetTheme Page property

I am using the Devexpress asp.net controls if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define them again.
Here's the link form msdn:[ASP.NET Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)
Read the fourth paragraph in the skins section. It's exactly what you wanted to know.

> (Default skins are matched exactly by control type, so that a Button control skin applies to all Button controls, but not to LinkButton controls or to controls that derive from the Button object.)

It sounds as if you could use the skinID for what you want though. Apple the named skin to both the button and it's derived control.

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess I dont have any alternative other than to either duplicate the skin definition or apply named skins...and next time I should RTFM before i ask :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're deriving from a base class, you inherit what that base class has, not what a particular instance of that base class contains.

Comment: Not sure if Understand...When you apply a skin through the Page styleSheetTheme property all instances of that control/class will be affected by the skin...

Comment: I would guess that the skin would be applied in that case.  Did you try it?  Remember, with inheritance, when B derives from A, B is still an "A".  I assume the constructor for the base class registers itself somewhere so skin changes are applied to it.  That will still happen with your derived class.